# monitor a file on mac os x

Tags: macos, watchdog, fswatch

There are a lot of similar posts out there, but none that does exactly what I want: I want a simple script, that watches a **folder on a Mac** for changes and passes the **filename** of the modified file to command/script when changes are detected.

The tool `inotifywait` doesn't exist on a mac. Folder events or `fswatch` or `watchdog` seem to be getting close, but it turns out they only watch *folders* or only return the *folder name*. `watchdog` might be doing what I need, but I could only find commands like this

```
watchmedo shell-command --recursive --command='echo ${watch_src_path}' .
```

which again only passes the *folder name* in the variable `watch_src_path`. Does anyone know how to get it (or another program) to pass on the file name of the changed file?

Answer (score 0):

Even if the question is very old, it may be useful to other people looking for the same functionality.  I wrote [`fsw`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fsw) exactly to fill this gap. `fsw` will give you the name of the changed paths and the *type* of change event.

Hope this helps.

Edited: `fsw` was merged with [`fswatch`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch).